# ko.validation is always undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

This is first time for me using ko validation. I don't know what i am missing, i tried to follow instructions in knockout.validation github, but still no luck. I have been struggling with this for more than hour, hope i will get help here.

I am loading my javascript lib in prerender event:

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DotNetNuke.Framework.ServicesFramework.Instance.RequestAjaxScriptSupport();
            DotNetNuke.Framework.ServicesFramework.Instance.RequestAjaxAntiForgerySupport();    
            ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(this.Page, this.ControlPath + "../Resources/javascript/knockout-2.3.0.js");              
            ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(this.Page, this.ControlPath + "../Resources/javascript/knockout.validation.js");    
        }
```

My view model:

```
    var mynamespace = mynamespace || {};
mynamespace.Container = "viewModelDiv";

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    ko.validation.configure({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: true,
    messageTemplate: null
});


    mynamespace.viewModel = {
        //Data        
        firstName: ko.observable().extend({ required: true }) ,       

        // Behaviors
        submit: function() {
            if (mynamespace.viewModel.errors().length == 0) {
                console.log('Thank you.');
            } else {
                console.log('Please check your submission.');
                mynamespace.viewModel.errors.showAllMessages();
            }
        },

        errors: function() {
            ko.validation.group(this);
        }

    }; // end of view model

    mynamespace.viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(mynamespace.viewModel);
    //ko.validation.registerExtenders();
    ko.applyBindings(mynamespace.viewModel, jQuery("#" + mynamespace.Container).get(0));    


});
```

all js files are being loaded successfully, i can see them in the browser. 
binding without validation is working fine too.

It just Whenever i hit ko.validation browser will return error message stating ko.validation is undefined.

Exact error message: ***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'configure' of undefined ***

Update: I tried it on jsfiddle and it is working! http://jsfiddle.net/cSxne/
BUT it doesn't work on my environment.!

Comment: I downloaded it though this: http://jsfiddle.net/KHFn8/2971/

Comment: i am using this version 'Knockout.Validation 1.0.1'